# How to verify facebook jest is installed successfully

Tags: facebook, jestjs

I followed the instructions to install Facebook jest on https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html#content :

```
npm install --save-dev jest-cli
```

After the install command I typed `jest` in the terminal, and press enter but It popped:

```
bash: jest: command not found.
```

But when I run the getting started sample by using `npm test` in the terminal, it worked well.

So, how can I verify that Facebook jest is installed successfully?

Comment: the command to run jest is 'jest' and you can use jest --verbose as well. only thing is you have to be in the project root when you are doing this.If the getting started sample works it should just work for other projects too

Comment: I already figure out, in the terminal, just input "jest", it will response "Using Jest CLI v14.1.0, jasmine2, babel-jest" something like this. 

and install jest use  global by using  "npm install -g jest-cli "
so that jest can use  in terminal anywhere

Comment: Try `npm install --force --save-dev jest`

Answer (score 7):

## Ways to install a package in npm

In `node.js` you have two ways to install a package: *globally* or *locally*.

#### The sintax is the following:

```
// globally
npm install -g [package_name]

// locally
npm install --save-dev [package_name]
```

So, now what it happens is that you run the local one which downloads the package in `node_modules` under your project folder.

To check you installed `jest` properly so you can check on your `node_modules` if there is a jest folder.

## How to check if jest is installed

In addition to that `npm` is creating a shortcut in you local `node_modules` under the directory `.bin` son in there you should find a link to jest.

#### You can test that like that:

```
cd your_project_folder
./node_modules/.bin/jest
```

## Why npm test works?

The reason why `npm test` works is because when you run it `npm` is going to look for the commands globally and locally.